# Is it correct to calculate NDBI using bands of different spatial resolutions?

Tags: sentinel-2

Is it correct to calculate NDBI using a 20m SWIR Sentinel-2 band and a 10m NIR Sentinel-2 band without resampling any of the two bands? And what will be the spatial resolution of output NDBI image in this case?

I am using this formula to calculate NDBI:
(SWIR-NIR)/(SWIR+NIR)

Answer (score 0):

The sort answer is no. You do not indicate what software you are using but, at some point for the raster algebra to work, resampling is occurring, else wise the the pixels will not overlay and the function would fail. The reason this is bad is that you are letting the software perform the resampling on-the-fly rather than making decisions on resampling yourself. Different resampling methods matter and for sometime ESRI products defaulted to nearest neighbor, which would be quite detrimental to your analysis. You should specify the resampling parameters and then operate on the derived data and not let the software do this automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got your point. But what do you suggest? Either I should make the course resolution band finer (through Pansharpening) or fine resolution band coarser (through resampling)?